# Save image to Android internal memory and then send as an Email using Intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, storage, internal

I wrote an app that uses Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) to find the folder to store images to.  I then write the jpg to that folder and then use the following code to allow the user to email, SMS, Facebook ... or whatever apps their phone has setup.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
  i.setType("image/jpg");   
  File shareImg =  new File(fileName);
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(shareImg)); 
  startActivity(i);
```

This code works fine on the devices I tested on.  Now I am finding that users that do not have an SD card are not able to use this code.  So I decided to try and write the image to internal memory.  I was able to write the image to my apps folder and set the access as Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE but when I fire off the intent, GMail, SMS, or any of the other maps just give me a message that they are unable to attach the image.  I thought the problem might be that the image wasn't in the actual "pictures" folder of the device but I couldn't find an routing equivalent to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) for internal storage.  Has anyone else been able to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing my code to use:

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

instead of:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

Comment: +1 for following up with your solution - you should accept your own answer as well, which is perfectly reasonable and desired (in order to make room for really unanswered questions and motivate others to look at these), as long as it has been a real open question in the first place. Thanks :)